# using task in generic producer/consumer

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, producer-consumer

I am trying to build a generic producer/ consumer with BlockingQueue.
i want it to be as multi threaded or parallel as possible yet not eating all of the computer resources.
let say we have one producer, is it better to have consumers as threads or one consumer with 
Tasks when consuming the data ?

```
while(true)  
{
   queue.TryTake(...) { Task.Factory.StartNew(...); }
}
```

**or**

```
Thread t = new Thread(Consumer.Start);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a combination.

Your first proposal has the problem that when the Queue is well filled you will start a lot of tasks, maybe too many.

The second one would use only 1 Thread (I assume that's what you mean here).

You should probably start N consumers and device some strategy for N. It depends very much on the amount of work, use of I/O  etc.

Possible strategies are

- N = NumberOfCores (- 1)
- Start a new Consumer when Queue.Count > M

And you might as well use a Task (with LongRunning option) instead of a Thread.

Comment: @guy: When they keep stacking up. Be careful not to move the burden from the blocking(!) collection to the Task queue.

Comment: got it .. that is a nice thought that i didn't think about.

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about computer resources a solution could be to do a pool of worker threads that all monitors the task queue and as soon as a task is put on queue and a worker thread is free it reads the it from the queue and starts working?

That should be quite easy to set up.

//daniel

Comment: the solution is just give the global thread pool to do his work with tasks , no ?

Comment: Sure, that's one way to do it. Along with some monitoring of the queue the work could be dispatched to the thread pool. At least if the tasks are not too long running.